# Must readers be called to the Torah by name?

Tags: names, torah-service

"I was in one place recently where they are very strict about calling people's names before they approach the Torah and another place where the people just came up one-by-one, having arranged beforehand who would read which *aliya*", said a friend to me recently.

Is there a mandate for calling people up by name, and if so, where is this requirement discussed?

Answer (score 7):

Shaalos U'Teshuvos Avnei Neizer Choshen Mishpat Siman 103 mentions that the Minhag by the Ashkenazim is to call up by the persons name and fathers name, since every Jews name and soul is alluded to in the Torah and has a part of the Torah.

However the Sephardim follow the Chida (Shaalos U'Teshuvos Chaim Shaal Chelek 1 Siman 13) that the Gabai goes over and tells the person to go up, the reason is based on Orach Chaim 139 that if a person is called up and refuses to go there is a curse of a shortened life.

Comment: in practice many places just call the third, fourth and son on instead of using peoples name. like you mentioned each one knows already when he is going. also it is common to sell the aliot

Comment: @Avraham, "many places": you mean _Ashk'nazi_ places?

Comment: The Sefardi synagogues in our area do not call up anyone.  They work it out ahead of time (or on the spot) who will get which aliyah.  The Ashkenazi synagogues do call up people.

Comment: @msh210 The Ashkenazi _Great Synagogue_ in Copenhagen calls by  number only. The gabbai hands out small cards to people beforehand, so they know when to go up. However, the smaller _Machazike HaDas_ calls by name, though historically they share minhagim.

Comment: Our current custom (ashkenazi shul) is to call up by name.  However, I can remember a time in the past (the 1960's - same shul) when the gabbai would hand out small cards to people beforehand and we would only call out then number of the aliyah.

Answer (score 4):

*SA OC* 135:11 reads:

> There's someone who says that if the *gabay* called a *kohen* or *levi* and he's not there, he should not call another by name, because of the *p'gam* of the first one. Rather, he should go up [to the *Tora*] by himself.

The *p'gam* of the first one means, according to *MB* :40, "that they'll think that it became known meanwhile [i.e., after he was called] that he's *pagum*".

It sounds to me from this like the custom was to call people by name. That doesn't answer the question about a *mandate*, though.

However, I do know as a practical matter that *S'faradi* synagogues — or at least Syrian (and IIRC Moroccan) ones I've been in — do *not* call people by name, despite the apparent implication of the *SA*. (*Ashk'nazi* synagogues I've been in do, for the most part.)

Answer (score 1):

In the shul I grew up in - Adas Yeshurun of Johannesburg - before Krias HaTorah the Gabbai would give somebody a card with ששי written on it.

For the  6th Aliya the Gabbai (or *Ba'al Segen*, actually) would simply announce **ויעמוד ששי**.

Since most (all, they would claim) of the Minhagim of the Shul came from Germany, this must have been the custom in some (all?) shuls there before the war.

Same procedure was used for מפטיר.

Comment: In your schul, was the 'oleh for the tochecho called up with יעמוד משעמד or with some similar formula?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - He (the president) was called up for the tochocho like every other person all year round.

Comment: That's apparently an old Frankfurter minhag, see the KAYJ forum (I forgot which post)

Comment: Makes sense, since we had a mix of Fürth (IIRC) and Frankfurt a.m. founders and minhogim.

Comment: Funny, my family's the same way on my paternal grandfather's side: Fürther u. Frankfurter.