# Titles and prefixes for calling people up to the Torah

Tags: minhag, names, torah-reading, torah-service, gabbai

When people are called up to the Torah by name, often there is a title that goes with them, such as "ha-bachur" for a young man, "ha-rav" for a rabbi (and/or someone with semicha), and other such titles.
....Or at least I assume "ha-bachur" is reserved for young men....today someone got called up for an aliyah; when asked for his name, he replied "ha-bachur Ploni etc." He appeared to be at least over 60 years old.

What do these titles mean, and where do they come from?

---

*[And, most urgently, was my elderly friend entitled to his use of the prefix "ha-bachur"???]*

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8689/5323

Comment: Is your elderly friend married? "Bachur" can be used ti mean bachelor rather than a young man specifically.

Comment: @Yishai I don't know....could be....

Comment: @Yishai In the local yeshiva, I discovered that those bochrim in the lower shiur are called "ha-bachur Ploni," while those in the upper shiur (even not yet dating!) are called "ha-chassan"

Comment: ....which led to an interesting story, where someone's mother got many 'mazal tov's when someone who didn't understand the system misinterpreted, and spread the word that "Ploni" was engaged ;)

Comment: I was just poking through my old, unanswered questions....for anyone wondering, "Ploni" is now married :D

Comment: If I were the gabbai and a man of 60 asked to be called "ha-bachur", I'd assume it was to make him feel young.  I'd say it, but I'd expect it to get a laugh.