# Must someone be called to the Torah at all?

Tags: torah-reading, torah-service

A followup to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8689/must-readers-be-called-to-the-torah-by-name?rq=1) question.

One of the practices I have seen in this pandemic age is that one individual gets all the aliyot (often the one doing the laining). In that case, not only is there no question about who gets the next aliyah, but there needs to be no notification of it. Does each aliyah have to be announced in any form or can the reader just go from making the "closing bracha" for one aliyah right into making the "opening bracha" for his next aliyah? Is there some independent purpose or need for announcing the aliyah?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%98_%D7%92

Comment: So would this mean that he needs to be called up for the first aliyah, or for each one?

Comment: A somewhat related and regularly more common situation is when a Kohen gets the second Aliyah as well when there is Levi. In that situation (from what I've seen) the Gabbai just says "Yaamod Bimkom Levi" and the Kohen goes ahead with the Brachos, which seems to imply that some form of call up still needs to be done. Of course, this case is a bit different, as there are other factors involved by a Kohen getting a different Aliyah (i.e. I recall that certain things related to the Kohen Aliyah are done to make sure the Kohen can't be misconstrued as a Chalal, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

See [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 139:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.139.3?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he):

> אפילו ראש הכנסת או חזן לא יקרא עד שיאמרו לו קרא ונהגו ששליח צבור כשרוצה מברך וקורא בלי נטילת רשות משום דהוי כאלו משעה שמינוהו לש"ץ הרשוהו על כך: הגה ובמדינות אלו אין נוהגין כן ואין החזן עולה רק כשהסגן אומר לו לעלות אבל אין קורין לו בשמו כמו שאר העולים שקוראים אותם בשמם פלוני בר פלוני.
>
> Even the president of the shul, or the chazan, shouldn't read from the Torah until they tell him to read. It is customary that the shliach tzibbur [i.e., baal korei] can say the berachos and read without being given permission, since it's as though he was implicitly given such permission when he was appointed.
>
> Rema: This is not the practice in these [Ashkenazic] countries: the chazan [baal korei] doesn't get an aliyah unless the segan [gabbai] tells him to. However, he's not called by name like other olim, who are called up by name, "Ploni son of Ploni."

So yes, an oleh does need to be called up or given permission somehow, at least implicitly.

Comment: This reflects what DoubleAA linked to in his comment, but this only seems to say that someone needs to be called up to start the reading. Once he is up there and he continues, does he need to keep being called for each aliyah?

Comment: @rosends That would be the "implicit" permission of the type given to the baal korei, no?

Comment: so according to the S"A, because the b"k has this implicit permission, he never needs to be called up but to the Rama, he would need to be called once?

Comment: @rosends I guess so.