# Does one call up to the Torah someone already "up"?

Tags: torah-reading, torah-service, covid19-pandemic

As a followup to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8689/must-readers-be-called-to-the-torah-by-name) question, the pandemic has created some interesting situations. In one shul in which I daven, on a Monday/Thursday the one who reads the Torah also receives all the aliyot. As such, once he is called up for the first aliyah, he is already at the Torah.

For his second and third aliyot, is there any reason to call him (by name or not by name) at all? Does there need to be an interruption between his "closing bracha" for one aliya and his "opening bracha" for the next aliya?

Comment: Are you asking about how to call someone up for two Aliyos in a row (which is what the body of your question implies), or how to call up someone already standing in the area (which is what your title says)? The latter isn't pandemic specific, even in the before-days the Ba'al Korei/Gabbai/random person standing on the Bimah could still get an Aliyah.

Comment: Are you a levi? This "interesting situation" existed preCOVID too when the kohein got two successive aliyot because no levi was present.

Comment: What I have seen when a kohein is called for the 2nd aliyah, the phrase "bimkom levi" is stated. In this shul, the person called up was not listed as "bimkom" anything, so there was no innovation in calling him up in anyone's stead which might have made his second calling up new and necessary (if it is necessary).

Comment: @Salmononius2 I mean "up" as in having been called up to the Torah previously.